# RSpec validations failing on associations made through Factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

Trying something simple and overlooking the obvious I'm sure. Shouldn't Factory_Girl be automatically creating the association? If so why does "GET index" spec below fail because `event_id` is *nil*?

Event has_many :posts

```
#post.rb
  ...
  belongs_to :event
  validates :event_id, :presence => true
  ...

#factories.rb
Factory.define :event do |event|
  event.name "The Long Event Title"
end

Factory.define :post do |post|
  post.title "This is a post"
  post.association :event
end


#posts_controller_spec.rb
before(:each) do
  @attr = Factory.attributes_for(:post)
end

describe "GET index" do
  it "assigns all posts as @posts" do
    post = @user.posts.create(@attr)    ### <-- event_id not assigned?
    # post = FactoryGirl.create(:post)  ### <-- this doesn't work either
    get :index
    assigns(:posts).should eq([post])
  end
end
```

**Edit:** Additional spec example:

```
describe "POST create" do
    describe "with valid params" do
      it "creates a new Post" do
        expect {
          post :create, :post => @attr, :event => Factory.create(:event)  <- fail
        }.to change(Post, :count).by(1)
      end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the FactoryGirl wiki: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/wiki/Usage

```
# Attribute hash (ignores associations)
user_attributes = Factory.attributes_for(:user)
```

So you are not getting an event_id, and that's why it's failing.

Also, you said you tried `post = FactoryGirl.create(:post)` but you should do `post = Factory.create(:post)` and that will get it to work.

Perhaps in your before() block you should just create and save the post, unless you have a test that requires it to not be saved yet.

Comment: so, what's the syntax if I want to pass an event with @attr? *see 2nd spec example above.*

Comment: You can do: `:post => @attr.merge(:event => Factory.create(:event))` and that will merge in the `:event` key (that points to a newly created Event object) in to the @attr hash, and then pass it along to your method.

Comment: Yeah, I just did that...feels clumsy though...but works fine. thx

Comment: Personally, I'd rather just create a post object in the before() section of your tests, and if you need a specialized one, you can always use `update_attributes` to change things, or build up a new one in your test. But this way, you always have a valid post object and can avoid repeating calls that might create it. But it depends on your style and what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
validates_presence_of :event_id
```

to

```
validates_presence_of :event
```

Comment: `validates_presence_of :event_id` is still okay. OP could add `validates_associated :event` though (not sure which version of Rails this is scoped to).